# Why xframe_options_exempt doesn't work for my Django view?

Tags: python, django, iframe, web, same-origin-policy

I want my view page to be loaded via iframe from another domain, so following Django doc, I add the decorator `@xframe_options_exempt` to my view. But when it is loaded in iframe, Chrome still reports:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.aaa.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://bbb.com".

And from DevTools Network tab, I see the response doesn't include 'X-Frame-options' header.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. In my case, I was raising an `Http404` error, which seems to somehow bypass the `@xframe_options_exempt` decorator. I suspect that if you are returning anything other than an `HttpResponse` object from your view, then your `xframe_options_exempt` decorator may not be performing as you might expect.

Note that the `Http404` class, for example, [does not inherit](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py) from `HttpResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

Include middleware in your ***settings.py*** file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Then include needed imports in your ***views.py*** file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already figured it out, but Django xframe_options_exempt sadly only works for HTTPResponse for current release (Mar. 2021).

An example of how to use it would be:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt 

@xframe_options_exempt
def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
    return HttpResponse("This page is safe to load in a frame on any site.")
```

For sameorigin and deny, it would be:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_deny
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_sameorigin

@xframe_options_deny
def view_one(request):
    return HttpResponse("Frame won't be displayed!")

@xframe_options_sameorigin
def view_two(request):
    return HttpResponse("Display onlly if from the same origin host.")
```

Referenced from [Django Clickjacking Protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/clickjacking/)